# Which all standard fields are synced between Opportunity to Quote and OpportunityLineItem and QuoteLineItem?

Tags: quote, sync

I want to know if there is any documentation which lists all the standard fields from Opportunity and Line Items that are synced on standard Quote Sync.

Comment: did you look [here in Help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=quotes_fields.htm&type=5) ?

Comment: yes.I think only Quantity and SalesPrice are updated during the sync.

Comment: I would imagine that CurrencyIsoCode, PricebookEntryId would also be sync'd